# lubuntu 100% cpu usage and massive freezes on chromebook

Tags: lubuntu, performance, chromebook

I am new to linux and I already searched the site and couldn't find anything that fixed it. But I installed lubuntu because my acer CB3-532 is too slow for many other linux Distros. After a new update I noticed it was a bit slower but I didn't mind a month later it keeps freezing and mouse is laggy and cpu usage peaks at 100% almost all the time I removed many of the duplicate programs from the update like the multiple text editors and task managers and it seemed to have sped it up a tiny bit but the freezes are driving me insane. Does anyone know what is causing this and what I can do to fix.
Edit: also forgot that my screen tears at any movement on screen.
Edit2: I am using 19.10 eoan

Comment: Did you have created a swap partition on the instalation?

Comment: oh I needed to create a swap partition?

Comment: You haven't provided Lubuntu release details, please do (desktop varies depending on release, which also means different software...)

Comment: I am using 19.10 eoan.